# Path equivalent in asp.net (C#)?

Tags: c#, path

Whats the equivalent to System.IO.Path ?

I got this url: http://www.website.com/category1/category2/file.aspx?data=123

How can i break this down, like

```
var url = ASPNETPATH("http://www.website.com/category1/category2/file.aspx?data=123");

url.domain <-- this would then return http://www.website.com

url.folder <-- would return category1/category2

url.file <-- would return file.aspx

url.queryString <-- would return the querystring in some format
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `UriBuilder` class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://www.somesite.com/requests/somepage.aspx?i=123");
string host = uriBuilder.Host;     // www.somesite.com
string query = uriBuilder.Query;   // ?i=123
string path = uriBuilder.Path;     // /requests/somepage.aspx
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [URI Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) you can get all of that information using that class.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are perfect to use for this.
Here's a link that has some nice info on using them.
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Edit : I forgot C# has a URI class which you can use for this as well.